# Pandas return index and column name based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say we have a DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'D': {'A': 0.810032, 'B': 0.752299, 'C': 0.224038},
    'E': {'A': 0.17714, 'B': 0.680405, 'C': 0.769732},
    'F': {'A': 0.942959, 'B': 0.436582, 'C': 0.269791}
})
print(df)
          D         E         F
A  0.810032  0.177140  0.942959
B  0.752299  0.680405  0.436582
C  0.224038  0.769732  0.269791
```

Is it possible to return index and column names into a list of tuples based on a condition, for instance

```
print(df < 0.25)
   D      E      F
A  False   True  False
B  False  False  False
C  True  False  False
```

I would like to end up with a list of tuples like:

```
[('A','E'),('C','D')]
```

Comment: try : ``A.lt(.25).stack().loc[lambda df: df].index.to_list()``

Comment: @DHJ Please do not edit your question to include the answer (Questions and Answers should be separate on SO). Just notify the commenter and ask them if they would like to post that as an answer like I did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to reshape the data and filter with the booleans:

```py
df.lt(.25).stack().loc[lambda df: df].index.to_list()

[('A', 'E'), ('C', 'D')]
```

Answer (score 4):

We can also use [`DataFrame.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) then [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) which takes advantage of the fact that [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) drops `NaN` values by default then use [`Index.tolist`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.to_list.html) to get the list of tuples:

```
results = df.where(df < .25).stack().index.tolist()
```

`results`:

```
[('A', 'E'), ('C', 'D')]
```